# web.config error handler for a Content-Type JSON

Tags: json, iis-7, web-config, content-type, http-status-code-422

This is my current situation (in the web.config file):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" >
     <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="inst\404.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

Our application has an error HTTP "422" (that is a Content-Type JSON). We need this JSON for the application to work properly.

BUT our IIS is sending the response like a Content-Type →text/html and the response is:

The custom error module does not recognize this error.`{"code":"XXX","message":"Message"}`

We tried to add in the web.config  `httpErrors tag:  existingResponse="PassThrough"` but the error 404 configuration stops working. We need both things to work (the error 404 configuration and the Content-Type JSON response for 422 errors).

It is not possible to modify our application, that is why we need a solution with the web.config file.

Comment: please show (the relevant parts of) the actual web.config then we can be clear what you're talking about, thanks.

Comment: I can hardly understand what is the issue and what you are trying to solve. Back to the basics, use a tool like Fiddler or simple developer tools of your browser, so show us what is the "error HTTP 422". Screenshots can save a thousand words. You also need to clearly tell what is the error of "the custom error module does not recognize this error". Again, show screenshots instead of using your own words.